# How to add custom column in container in azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, containers, storage, azure-blob-storage

How to add a custom column in azure blob container? I want to add a column with choice to determine the file type. Ex: medical file, finance file, without writing plugin.

Comment: COuld you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: Hi James,  I am trying to store all the files in dynamics 365 to azure blob storage. I integrated azure blob with dynamics 365, now I want to know if I  can add metadata when uploading file in dynamics? When uploading a file in dynamics, i want to specify whether it is a medical file or finance file in a field called document type. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi @amrutha, blobs in container does support metadata attribute, you could also put different type of files in different container. or use a storage table to keep the file name, type, any other metadata and url.

Comment: Hi @Sujit Singh, Thank you for reply. Can I add metadata to azure blob containers and blobs from other system also? For example from Dynamics 365? When I am uploading a file in dynamics 365, it will create a entity specific containers in azure blob. Ex: all the files uploaded in account table will be stored in account container and all the file uploaded in contact table will be stored in contact container. So if i have different types of files in each table and if I set file type metadata to each blobs, can I still store them in different container based on the file type?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add some additional tags or identifier to your containers to determine the file types in the container, you can do this easily by adding container metadata, just as below:

[image]

Besides on Azure Portal. You can also do this [by REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-container-metadata) or [SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-container-properties-metadata?tabs=dotnet).

For individual files, you can also set metadata for them, details see [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/organize-blobs-properties-metadata/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply... It is very useful.              I want to know if it is possible to add metadata from dynamics 365. I am using azure blob storage to store all the files in dynamics 365. Can I add metadata when uploading file in dynamics 365?

Comment: @amruthavarshini, I see, I am not so familiar with dynamics 365, if filename is the only one that you are allowed to modify before you upload, how about add some prefix to your file? such as medical/<filename>. And is there any doc about integrate dy365 ans storage ? I'll look into it

Comment: @amruthavarshini, how's going? Has your issue got solved now ?

Comment: Hi @stanley Gong, I am still looking on whether I can add metadata to azure blob storage from other systems or not (mainly from Dynamics 365 ).                                                  I am using a 3rd party connector to integrate azure blob with dynamics 365. They dont have the feature of adding metadata.